# Index Error, countdown calendar not working

Tags: python, tkinter

Can you help me with my code?

I wanted an if-else statement, that if there is no description for the festival is given, it displays there is no info about that particular festival. But for that, I would have to do `if not(event[2])` but for that, it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kanav_i4cko4c\Downloads\My first tkinter program.py", line 52, in <module>
    if (event[2]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is the source code for `festivals.txt`

```
Diwali,5/11/21
Christmas,25/12/21
```

---

Here is the source code for the main program

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, simpledialog, messagebox
from datetime import date, datetime

# function get_events is to get the celebration events
def get_events():
    list_events = []
    with open('festivals.txt') as file:
          for line in file:
                line1 = line.rstrip('\n')
                global current_event
                current_event = line1.split(',')
                print('Check 0')
                print(current_event)
                current_event[1] = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%d/%m/%y').date()
                list_events.append(current_event)
    return list_events


def days_between_dates(date1, date2):   
    time_between = str(date1 - date2)
    number_of_days = time_between.split(' ')
    return number_of_days[0]

# End of Functions
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main program starts here

root = Tk()
root.title('Calendar')

c = Canvas(root, width=2000, height=800, bg='dark blue')
c.pack()
c.create_text(100, 50, anchor='w', fill='white', font=' Times 40 bold underline',
              text='My Countdown Calendar')
c.create_rectangle(30, 10, 60, 1000,
            outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

events = get_events()
today = date.today()

# Make a dictionary for the festivals



vertical_space = 100
events.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
horizontal_space = 100

for event in events:
    event_name = event[0]
    days_until = days_between_dates(event[1], today)
    if (event[2]):
        display = 'It is %s days until %s. %s =  %s' % (days_until, event_name, event_name,event[2])
    else:
        display = 'It is %s days until %s. There is no info on %s' % (days_until, event_name, event_name)
    if (int(days_until) <= 50):
        text_col = '#c11a2b'
    else:
        text_col = 'SkyBlue1'
    c.create_text(100, vertical_space, anchor='w', fill=text_col,
                    font='Calibri 28 bold', text=display)
    vertical_space = vertical_space + 30
    horizontal_space = horizontal_space + 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you evaluate `event[2]` it attempts to retrieve the 3rd item in the list which isn't there so python raises an exception.

One solution could be by initializing your list with default values:

```
event = [None for i in range(3)]
```

This way there is a `None` value at `event[2]` which can be evaluated by your if statement.

Another solution could be to simply check whether the list contains less than 3 items:

```
if len(event) <= 2:
    # do something
```

Comment: `event = [None for i in range(3)]` could also be written as `event=[None]*3`

Comment: @ILoveHistory you're welcome! Please mark as solved if I was able to help you out =]